# Connect Raspberry Pi 3 to Sql-Server and Cloud

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, odbc, cloud

I have been working on a project to read data with raspberry Pi 3 and send them to ubidots cloud and sql-server.
First i tried out to send to ubidots and it worked perfectly. After that, i sended to sql-server using pyodbc and FreeTDS. Now, i have a problem when i want to do it at the same time. The problem only happens using the raspberry, i tried out using a PC with ubuntu 16.04 and program runs fine.

When i run this code on python using raspberry with parameters of my server, the function pyodbc.connect breaks and shows "=====RESTART====" in the python Shell, but if i comment the "import request" the programs do the connection and continue normally doing print(1).

`import pyodbc
import requests
con=pyodbc.connect("DSN=XXXXXX;UID=XXXXXX;PWD=XXXXX;DATABASE=XXXXX")
print (1)`

Edit

I ran the code with python3 on terminal and i got the following failed message
`python3: malloc.c:2372: sysmalloc: Assertion (old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long) old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.`

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue

Comment: I didn't solve it yet

Comment: I encountered this issue while using OpenCV's VideoCapture to open images. Switching to imread solved my bug, but I still don't know what caused it, or why I was able to fix it. Maybe it's an issue to do with functions that don't properly clean up the memory they use?